# Why does my model accuracy rise and then drop, with the loss sharing similar characteristics?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem using Keras. I have nearly 17k training data, and approximately 14k testing data (validation comes from the 17k training data). I have a number of issues with my model which I would describe as follows:

- Validation accuracy starts with a high of ~51% after three epochs and then starts decreasing to the point of after 100 epochs the validation accuracy is ~23%.
- Validation loss value starts of at 6.2354, decreases for two epochs, increases for 10 epochs and then starts lowering again.
- Training accuracy also decreases after 20 epochs reaching a high of ~40% and then slowly dropping with slight fluctations.

The above issues all occur while the loss value for the model is continually dropping. If anyone could help with this model it will be greatly appreciated.

In my code, I am each piece of data contains 4096 values each of which are floating point values, and I am trying to classify a class that comes in the form of a size 10 array that contains a number of 0s and 1s depending on the class that it is trying to classify.

I've also included a visual depictions of the way in which the loss value is behaving in the model for 100 epochs.

Code:

```
final_model = Sequential()

final_model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu', input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

final_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

final_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))


final_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))

final_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

cust = RMSprop(lr=0.00001, rho=0.9)

final_model.compile(optimizer=cust, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

history = final_model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=128, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Why adding dropout right after the input layer?(we don't want to throw our inputs on the first layer itself), it seems that your model is overfiting as the training loss is decreasing but the validation is seeming to hit the constant, Try to deepen the net if you have sufficient data available, Also do split the data properly

Comment: Do you have any reason to be using that optimizer?  I would advise using SGD initially and then dividing the learning rate until it becomes rather small and see if accuracy begins to improve.